# PigUnit test failed due to brackets and comma's

Tags: unit-testing, apache-pig

I am trying to create a PIG script which changes the order of the columns. This is what I have come up with so far :

```
inputdata = LOAD 'path/to/file/on/hdfs' USING PigStorage() AS (param1:chararray, param2:chararray, param3:chararray);
outputdata = FOREACH inputdata GENERATE param1, param3, param2;
DUMP outputdata;
```

I've not tried this yet on HDFS but I figured I'd go ahead and write the unit test first. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Unit Test code :

```
PigTest test = new PigTest("path_to_script.pig");
FixHadoopOnWindows.runFix();

String[] input = {
    "valueparam1\tvalueparam2\tvalueparam3"
};

String[] output = {
    "valueparam1\tvalueparam3\tvalueparam2"
};

test.assertOutput("inputdata", input, "outputdata", output);
```

The FixHadoopOnWindows bit is a fix so I can run my unit tests on a windows machine easily. I found it in some blog and it helped resolve the permission issues I was having.

So now my tests run, but the problem is that the assertOutput fails. When I check the difference, I get this:

Expected:

```
valueparam1    valueparam3    valueparam2
```

Actual:

```
(valueparam1,valueparam3,valueparam2)
```

So I'm getting these brackets and comma's I never asked for. Now I'm not sure whether this is a bug in my unit testing code or in my actual script so any advice to get me started would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok. The brackets mean that your relation outputdata consists of a tuple with three values.

If you later want to store your data separated by tabs just do `STORE outputdata INTO 'dest' USING PigStorage('\t');`

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#Data+Types+and+More

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The PigUnit reads out the outputdata value, which is a Tuple in PIG. It's not until I store it to file, that the tuples are converted to a tab separated record.